# sql newbi - need to copy address_3 from inactive dup record to active address_3

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with about 200k addresses.  Some are inactive others are active.  the inactive ones are duplicates of my active ones.  Some of the active ones do not have the address_3 (community names) but the some inactive duplicates do have address_3.  I need to being the inactive address_3 into the duplicate match that is active.  I'm struggling with the structure.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Not enough information. How do we match a duplicate to the active record? Are the inactive ones timestamped or how would we choose which address to use if multiple inactive records have different address_3's?

Comment: the pkey id is a serial.  When I flagged the dupes I grouped by address1, address2, city, state, zip and kept the max id and made all others active = false.  all are timestamped at created.  if there are multiple address 3's then lets select the max id of the inactive one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a field called address_1 or something that we can group by, I would:

• Create an empty table (by reusing the DDL from your existing table).
• Populate that table with rows where address_3 IS NOT NULL and make sure you GROUP BY the appropriate column (example shown below).

I would run the SELECT without the INSERT to make sure that you have the correct data.

```
INSERT INTO second_addresses_table
SELECT
    a.address_1, 
    -- #other columns...
    a.address_3, 
    TRUE -- #default to Active = TRUE
FROM 
    first_addresses_table a
WHERE
    a.address_3 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    a.address_1,
    -- #other columns...
    a.address_3
```